# Can someone help me with the pointer version of this function

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having trouble trying to come up with the pointer version of this function:

```
void strncpy(char t[], const char s[], const unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;

   for(i = 0; i < n and s[i]; i++)
       t[i]=s[i];
   t[i] = '\0'
}
```

This function is supposed to copy the first "n" characters of one array to another array and then terminate with a null character. I'm sure this is simple but I'm still learning pointers :P

This is what I have right now:

```
void strncpy(char * t, const char * s, const unsigned int * n)
{ 
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < *n and *s; i++)
        *t = *s;
    *t = '\0';
}
```

Im calling it in main via:

```
char array_one[5] = "quiz";
char array_two[5] = "test";

unsigned int x = 2;
strncpy(array_one,array_two,x);
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? :)

Comment: @PYA ive tried: for(i = 0; i < * n and *s; i++). When i call the function I keep getting "invalid conversion" even though im using an unsigned int in the place of n

Comment: i'd recommend coming up with a solution and positing it here so we can help you with the part you are struggling with. No one will want to write the entire function for you - and thats not what you want anyway if you want to learn.

Comment: @JonathanPotter https://wandbox.org/permlink/2qRcmNonqt2J4l3b . not a keyword but works :P, not good practice though.

Comment: @PYA under section 2.5 of the C++ [specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) `and` is an alternative keyword for `&&`.

Comment: @fredrik oh i didnt know that - thanks :)

Comment: Concerning parameters of functions in C++ (and C): `char t[]` and `char *t` result in the exact same parameter type (because arrays always decay to pointers in function parameters). I believe, the `const unsigned int *n` is over enthusiastic, `const unsigned int n` (as in your first version) is more reasonable. Did you try just to replace x`[]` by `*`x? The above said, be aware that your first version already works with pointers (although you might not have been realized this).

Answer (score 0):

You've failed to increment the pointers, so you're always overwriting the same address.   There's also no need to pass `n` via a pointer:

```
#include <cstddef>

void my_strncpy(char *t, const char *s, std::size_t n) {
    while (n && *s) {
        *t++ = *s++;
        --n;
    }
    *t = '\0';
}
```

NB: note use of `size_t` to duplicate the standard parameter signature 
of the standard `strncpy` function, although the standard version also returns the original value of `t` rather than `void`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>

// changing the function signature to take an int instead of
// pointer to int - cleaner
void my_strncpy(char * t, const char * s, const unsigned int n)
{ 
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *t++ = *s++; // copy and increment
    }
    *t = '\0'; // fixing - added terminating char
}


int main(void)
{
    char  a[] = "string1";
    char b[] = "string2";

    my_strncpy(a,b,7); // replace 7 with appropriate size

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

You need to copy over each character from one string to another and then increment the pointers - you were missing that in your implementation. 
I also assume that you will not overshoot the array you are copying from.

Comment: @Alnitak i'd appreciate some details :)

Comment: compare the OP's non-array version with yours and you'll see two omissions.

Comment: @PYA thanks for the response. After I changed the inside of my for loop to "i < n" i now get the error "forbids the comparison between a pointer and integer"

Comment: @Justin i think your n is still a pointer - in my code i change it to an integer. `void strncpy(char * t, const char * s, const unsigned int * n)
 ` should be `void strncpy(char * t, const char * s, const unsigned int n)`

Comment: @Alnitak updated to add that my code assumes not going over the source array.

Comment: My n is definately not a pointer now, and im still getting the same error :(

Comment: @Justin can you post updated code? also take a look at a working implementation here https://wandbox.org/permlink/OpwdSibTKI60bTPO

Comment: @Justin any luck?